# Require is not defined using ReactJs with babel and webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm getting this error on Chrome developer tools:
"Uncaught Reference: Require is not defined"

webpack.config

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'app.js',
        path: __dirname + "public/scripts"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.jsx?$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ["env", "react"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "widget",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Diogo Matias",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "npm": "^5.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.3",
    "react-leaflet": "^1.7.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  }
}
```

This error comes from the import on my source javascript file where I have:

```
 import {GoogleMap, Marker} from "react-google-maps";
```

I use the cdn for react and react-dom. I'm used to use live-server and I'm new to webpack. I run with webpack-dev-server on the root directory.
Hope that is enough for you to help me.

Thanks.

Comment: You only have `babel-loader` for `jsx` files but your entry point is a `js` file. `test: /\.js$/,` should fix it.

Comment: Make sure your babel presets looks like this {
    "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimum configuration to get you started. Issue `npm run start` to bring up webpack-dev-server at port 9000. `babel-core` was missing from your configuration.

#### project structure

```
├── build
│   └── index.html
├── package.json
├── src
│   └── app.js
└── webpack.config.js
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "widget",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Get started with Webpack!",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "Diogo Matias",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "leaflet": "^1.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.3",
    "react-leaflet": "^1.7.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
  }
}
```

#### webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    compress: true,
    port: 9000
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /.jsx?$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

#### .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["last 3 Chrome versions"]
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

#### build/index.html

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is only missing the presets on the webpack.config.js. Don't mean to sound ungrateful. Thanks very much, totally made my day.

Comment: Although this, I do enjoy to ask for the command to run webpack automatically whenever there is a change in the files?